# Mac App Store Reviewer says "It appears Kiwi fails codesign verification"

Tags: objective-c, macos, appstore-approval, codesign, mac-app-store

But it clearly does not fail on my system.  The Verification test in XCode during the submission should (I assume) test this.  And running codesign on the command line of the archived app results in:

/Users/iac/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/272860A0-961E-47E7-B62F-0F7D373D938A.apparchive/Kiwi.app: valid on disk
/Users/iac/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/272860A0-961E-47E7-B62F-0F7D373D938A.apparchive/Kiwi.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Anyone run into something like this before?

Thanks,
Isaiah

Comment: Are you signing it with a development or release certificate?

Comment: just to make sure i was answering with real info, i've double checked the signature.  it was signed with my application certificate.  the "Developer Certificate Utility" lists its type as "Mac App".  this is also the same certificate i used to sign another variant of the same app (the free variant) that has been accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of back and forth the app was placed back "In Review" (without any change to the binary).  It was then rejected again for another odd reason (No non-apple installers allowed) after which it was again placed back "In Review," (again without any changes to the binary).

After a few more emails it finally received a rejection that made sense:  a few files in my resource folder had overly restrictive permissions.

So the answer is:  double-check your file permissions or be doomed to weeks of confusion.

Isaiah